# How do I restore Magento Cloud environments deleted by GitHub integration?

Tags: magento2, cli, cloud, github

I followed [the instructions](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/integrations/github-integration.html) to setup a GitHub integration with my Magento Cloud Pro project. This project has not been made live yet, but has been in development for several months and therefore has 1k+ commits. I took a snapshot of my Integration environment and ran the command as documented:

```
magento-cloud integration:add --type=github --project ...
```

There were additional prompts that appeared after running, with what seemed to be reasonable defaults, which I accepted.

```
Build pull requests (--build-pull-requests)
Build every pull request as an environment? [Y|n] 

Build pull requests post-merge (--build-pull-requests-post-merge)
Build pull requests based on their post-merge state? [y|N] 

Clone data for pull requests (--pull-requests-clone-parent-data)
Clone the parent environment's data for pull requests? [Y|n] 

Fetch branches (--fetch-branches)
Fetch all branches from the remote (as inactive environments)? [Y|n] 

Prune branches (--prune-branches)
Delete branches that do not exist on the remote? [Y|n]
```

After the last question it created a webhook and created the integration.

Oh, then it deleted all my environments apart from **Master**, **Production**, and **Staging**.

[image: Bye bye bye]

I'm guessing it's the last prompt that screwed me up `--prune-branches`. Shame on me for not pausing to consider what that might do (*note:* this option isn't documented in [the instructions](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/integrations/github-integration.html)).

**What can I do to restore these environments?**

Unlike deleting an environment through the Magento Cloud GUI, these appear to be *gone*. They aren't there and deactivated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Magento Support, this isn't possible. They referenced https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/env/environments-start.html#env-delete